# Client side javascript does not work

Tags: xpages

In my application I have a button:

```
<xp:button value="Say Hello" id="btnHello">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script>
            <![CDATA[alert('Hello World!');]]>
        </xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

It generated this code:

```
<button class="xspButtonCommand" type="button" name="view:_id1:_id2:_id9:btnHello" id="view:_id1:_id2:_id9:btnHello">Say Hello</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function view__id1__id2__id9__id28_clientSide_onclick(thisEvent) {
        alert('bbbbbbb');
    }
    XSP.addOnLoad(function() {
    XSP.attachEvent("view:_id1:_id2:_id9:_id28", "view:_id1:_id2:_id9:btnExport", "onclick", view__id1__id2__id9__id28_clientSide_onclick, false, 2);
    }); 
</script>
```

When I click on the btnHello button, nothing happens. Does anyone know where the problem could be?

Comment: Your button code works fine for me. Create a new database with default settings, create a new XPage and put the code in it. This should work for you too. Then go from there.

Comment: Inspect the browser console and see if any js error is logged. Likely js failed somewhere else and everything after it won’t run properly

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with third-party js library. I pasted it into a standard Notes javascript library and used it in xPage as a script resource. But Notes compiler or whatever it is could not resolve this library and therefore no script worked at all. Funny thing is that this library works fine in the normal web environment. Not in Notes environment.

So, problem solved. A third-party library is out and this particular script works all right, now. I guess IBM Notes with xPages is a real old school thing.